# how to convert emacs org outline with clock entries to csv file

Tags: org-mode

Newbie Emacs org question.

Wanted to export my tasks into a CSV reading spreadsheet program. How would one do that? If it is in the manual, could please point me to it?

Sample:

```
* A
** A1
   CLOCK: [2015-08-01 Sat 19:33]--[2015-08-01 Sat 19:33] =>  0:00
* B
* C
** Ok something about C
   CLOCK: [2015-08-01 Sat 19:35]--[2015-08-01 Sat 19:36] =>  0:01

#+BEGIN: clocktable :maxlevel 2 :scope subtree
#+CAPTION: Clock summary at [2015-08-01 Sat 19:36]
| Headline                   | Time   |      |
|----------------------------+--------+------|
| *Total time*               | *0:01* |      |
|----------------------------+--------+------|
| \emsp Ok something about C |        | 0:01 |
#+END:
```

Comment: An expected sample of CSV output would help us all quite a bit.

Comment: @PythonNu: Apologize for long time no reply. My personal requirement is pretty basic:
`Date, Time, Hour(s) (in decimal format),` is for billing on tasks. Does this make things clearer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is really what you want but I wrote a keyboard macro that will turn a line like this

```
   CLOCK: [2015-08-01 Sat 19:33]--[2015-08-01 Sat 19:33] =>  0:00
```

into this

```
2015-08-01 Sat 19:33,2015-08-01 Sat 19:33,0:00
```

To use it, eval this

```
(setq last-kbd-macro
   [?\C-a ?\M-z ?\[ ?\C-s ?\] ?\C-r ?\C-m ?\M-z ?\[ ?, ?\C-s ?\] ?\C-r ?\C-m ?\C-u ?\C-d ?\M-  ?\C-? ?, ?\C-n ?\C-a])
```

(`M-:` is the key to eval) and then run the macro with `C-x e`

Here's a more verbose breakdown of the macro:

```
C-a         ;; move-beginning-of-line
M-z         ;; zap-to-char
[           ;; self-insert-command
C-s         ;; isearch-forward
]           ;; self-insert-command
C-r         ;; isearch-backward
RET         ;; help-follow
M-z         ;; zap-to-char
[           ;; self-insert-command
,           ;; self-insert-command
C-s         ;; isearch-forward
]           ;; self-insert-command
C-r         ;; isearch-backward
RET         ;; help-follow
C-u C-d         ;; delete-char
M-SPC           ;; just-one-space
DEL         ;; scroll-down-command
,           ;; self-insert-command
C-n         ;; next-line
C-a         ;; move-beginning-of-line
```